# onclicking button only the last post changes

Tags: php

no matter whichever btn i click only the last post's count changes...how do i get the corresponding count to change

```
    <?php 
    // Query the custom post type to display

        $args = array('post_type' => 'books');
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
                $query->the_post();
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): 
                $postid = get_the_ID();
                $oldcount=get_field('count');
                $newcount=$oldcount+1;                              
    ?>
        <form action="#" method="post">
        <div><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?><input id="<?php echo $postid;?>" type="submit" name="submit" value="Vote" /><?php echo " ".$oldcount;?></div>
        </form>

    <?php endif; endwhile; ?>

<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $ID = $_GET['id'];
    echo $ID;
    echo " button clicked";    
    update_field('field_55014a',$newcount,$ID); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: so far iit doesn't ...it was suggested tag...and i added it as maybe there's a way using javascript to get the desired output and i donno javascript at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are submitting the form via POST but trying using `$_GET['id']` this does not correspond to `<input id="<?php echo $postid;?>">`

Change the form so that it submits the post id:

```
 <?php
 // THIS PORTION OF THE CODE MUST COME FIRST!!!!!
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $newcount = // query your database, get the vote count then add one.
     update_field('field_55014a',$newcount,$id); 
     header('Location: '. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
     exit();
 }

 $args = array('post_type' => 'books');
 $query = new WP_Query( $args );
 while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
     $query->the_post();
     if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
         $postid = get_the_ID();
         $votecout =get_field('count');
     ?>
         <form action="" method="POST">
             <div>
             <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
             <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $postid; ?>" name="id" />
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Vote" />
             <?php echo $oldcount; ?>
             </div>
         </form>
    <?php
    } // close if
} // close while
```

Comment: @user3117694 was there a reason you un-accepted the answer?

Comment: yea ...i donno y the reply didn't get updated...the problem with the code is ...say i have 2 buttons ...when i click on say 2 then first time it increments the count of btn 1 but after that when i clcik on btn second time it increments the count of btn 2...same for btn 1...y isn't it incrementing the corresponding count immediately

Comment: i m gonna post u a link to the live demo...give me few mins

Comment: say i click on vote btn for image 3 first time then count for image 4 increments , but second time count for image 3 increases. like wise if i click for btn for image 2 then first time count of image3 increase on 2nd click count of image 2 increase

Comment: @user3117694, It looks like you only half heartedly took my advice. You are not issuing a redirect and you are not updating the database before you recreate the form. I put the database update stuff before printing the form for a reason. **Modify your code so that it is exactly as it is in the answer and you will see your issue go away.**

Comment: when i put header('Location: '. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); it redirects to home page instead of refreshing and loading same page

Comment: ok i removed only tht line and move the code above and it works now

Comment: hey rob...is it possible that i make the btn active to only when the user is logged in via facebook/twitter/g+ ...if yes plz guide